# Java: Write a string n times

Tags: java, for-loop

Ok this might be a stupid question but how can I write a for loop in order to have `x` `n` times.

I need my output to be like this (separated by commas): `x1, x2, x3, ..., x100`

I try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        String[] labels = "x" + i; 
    }
    System.out.println(labels + ","); 
}
```

Comment: Easiest way would be to print directly in the loop and have a conditional to check when you're at the end to prevent a comma printed at the very end of the string (or get rid of it after the loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        labels.add("x" + i);
    }
    System.out.println(String.join(", ", labels));
}
```

A couple errors in your code:

- You're trying to assign a string to an array of strings which is not possible
- You're trying to reference to `labels` outside of the scope it's declared in

Comment: Another error would be trying to print an array directly which would result in the default `toString()` return value + `","`. That should either be `Arrays.toString(...)` or how you suggested it.

Answer (score 2):

```
IntStream.range(1, 100).mapToObj(val -> "x" + val).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String []args){
    int n = 100;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i <= n-1; i++) {
       sb.append("x" + i + ","); 
    }
    sb.append("x"+n);
    System.out.println(sb.toString()); 
 }
```

Assuming you take n as an input (I have hardcoded it 100 for demonstration purpose).
Till n-1 we need comma separated values so put them inside the loop and for the nth term we don't want a comma in the end, so that would be outside the loop. 
Alternately, you could simply use Sysouts instead of appending to StringBuilder